# Extract content of <Script> in Python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to extract value of window.**FEED__INITIAL__STATE**

[Piece of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4OSZ.png)

How can I do it?

Comment: It is always recommended to paste the code here rather than show a picture of it. That way people can copy the code and make changes to it in case your code is incomplete/wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def check_script_tag(url):

    r = requests.get(url)
    parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="html.parser")

    try:
        text = parsed_html.body.find('script').text
        print (text)  # Here text in script tag !!
    except AttributeError:
        print("There is no script tag !!")

check_script_tag("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

Answer (score -1):

First, we have to find all the scripts tag and then match it,

p.s - updated in [RasitAydin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9649669/rasit-aydin) code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def check_script_tag(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="html.parser")

    script_tags = parsed_html.body.find_all('script')
    for script_tag in script_tags:
        text = script_tag.text
        if 'window.FEED__INITIAL__STATE'.lower() in text.lower():
            print(text)


check_script_tag(" YOUR WEB URL")
```